# How does Wild Card: Side Bets really work? (Spoiler)

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

This is my first playthrough and I think I have done things backwards compared to what the designers intended. I scoured all of the wasteland and did all the DLC before I even set foot in New Vegas. Now I feel slightly confused, especially from the [Wild Card](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Wild_Card:_Ace_in_the_Hole) quests or more specifically - [Wild Card: Side Bets](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Wild_Card:_Side_Bets).

I suspect that all my actions towards the factions before I arrived at New Vegas already has determined the outcome because the only thing I could say to the `Yes Man` was that I ignored any faction he mentioned, whether I was idolized or vilified with them. Now I have really no idea what that means or what other options I could have.

My affiliation is roughly on the good (or less evil) side (BoS, NCR, Boomers etc) and I have tried to pretty much wipe out anything gang-related (Vipers, Khans, Powder Gangers etc). I'm also currently neutral to The Legion.

Could someone explain what this quest is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of factions in the Mojave that have the power to affect the outcome of the final stages of the game and/or the ending in some way.  The point of the "Side Bets" quest is to get you to interact with (or ignore) these factions, who you might not run into unless you're prompted to do so.

Normally, the NCR/House/Legion quest lines will force you to interact with these factions and gain their support (or prevent them from supporting your enemies) as part of storyline missions, but if you're playing the Yes Man/Wild Card track, there's a lot more freedom in who you deal with/kill/etc.  Thus, Yes Man can be told that you wish to ignore them, since obtaining their loyalty might be impossible depending on your previous decisions.

It's certainly possible to win while ignoring *all* of these factions - in fact, following the Yes Man track can take you from the start to the end of the game in under a couple of hours, if you play your cards right.  Having some or all of these guys on your side can make things easier, though.

Comment: That was quite elaborate but I must admit that I've never been so confused about choices as when playing NV. I'll just have to playthrough it all and see where it gets me.

Comment: @Sandokan, the Yes Man track is very chaotic, because it's designed as a "catch all" for when you decide to go anarchistic or just feel like murdering everyone.  Unlike in Skyrim, for instance, plot-critical characters aren't marked "essential" and unkillable - this game will let you paint yourself into a corner, and even gives you an out if you do so :)  The Yes Man track is far less scripted, though, and I agree that it can be confusing for a first playthrough.

Comment: So basically you have the choices of NCR, Legion or House if you want to do it "orderly" and Yes Man if you're more towards "go nuts"?

Comment: @Sandokan, pretty much, yeah.  Yes Man's track keeps the game from just coming to a screeching halt if you end up vilified with everyone and/or you kill plot-critical characters.  Yes Man "himself" is one of the few unkillable NPCs.

Comment: I think technically even the Yes Man is killable but there just are an almost unlimited supply of securitron bodies for him to jump into. But not sure if this is valid ingame, or just some lore I read.

Comment: @Ids, I think Victor is this way, and I think he remarks on it at one point.  I had thought it impossible to kill Yes Man, but the Wikia says it's possible, and even permanent deaths are possible for him.  I have to imagine that's a bug :P